# mongodb：DBQuery.Option.noTimeout is not defined

Tags: mongodb

I am writing a mongo shell script which takes a lot time, and it timeout finally.
I know it will be solved by using "addOption(16)", but I get it from mongo offical that I should use "addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout)". But it's not work and throws exception:
DBQuery.Option has not property.

Anyone can tell me why and give me a reference？
Thanks！

Tips:
Don't surprised my poor english and because I am a chinese, and I am a rookie too..

**supplement：**

the code：

```
db.track.find().forEach(function(item){
        db.location.update({'track_id':item._id,user_id:{$ne:item.user_id}},{$set:{user_id:item.user_id}},false,true);
});
```

The above script need a long time， and to avoid mongoCursor timeout， I write as below：

```
db.track.find().addOption(16).forEach(function(item){
        db.location.update({'track_id':item._id,user_id:{$ne:item.user_id}},{$set:{user_id:item.user_id}},false,true);
```

and it work as well.

But I get it from:
[mongo doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.addOption/#DBQuery.Option.noTimeout)

that I should use:

```
db.track.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout).forEach(function(item){
            db.location.update({'track_id':item._id,user_id:{$ne:item.user_id}},{$set:{user_id:item.user_id}},false,true);
```

and I try it but it throw exception:

```
Mon Nov 11 18:09:58 TypeError: DBQuery.Option has no properties d:\demodata\mong
o.js:22
failed to load: d:\demodata\mongo.js
```

Environment：

OS: ubuntu3.8

mongo:2.0.4

Comment: Improve the formatting by putting the code in the 'code format'. Also Give info about your setup (version of mongo, libs ...etc). Best

Comment: @dzada Thanks for your time！ I have already added the code

Comment: Wait, what is 'code format' I'm having this same issue.